# How can I resize a dynamic array of pointers without using a vector

Tags: c++, arrays

If I wanted to resize this array:

```cpp
int array[5];
```

I would do this:

```cpp
int* temp = new int [n];
...
array = temp;
```

But, how would I do it if I have this array?

```cpp
int *array[5];
```

Maybe like this?

```cpp
int** temp = new int* [n];
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> array(n);`

Comment: What If I don't want to use a vector?

Comment: If you don't want to use a vector you have to write code to manage memory and copy objects. If you want to do that as a learning experience, there are many traps that you'll run into. If you want to do that to create serious code, don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *CAN'T* resize a fixed array, period.  Its size is constant, determined at compile-time.

You *CAN'T* assign a `new[]`'ed pointer to a fixed array, either.

So, neither of your examples will work.

In your 1st example, you would need this instead:

```cpp
int* array = new int [5];
```

And in your 2nd example, you would need this instead:

```cpp
int** array = new int* [5];
```

Either way, don't forget to `delete[]` the `array` before assigning something new to it, eg:

```cpp
int* array = new int [5];
...
int* temp = new int [n];
...
delete[] array;
array = temp;
```